# Disable the submission of a form

Tags: forms

I need to make a form read-only under certains conditions : what I did is to not add the `$form['submit']` button.

This way I can't submit the form. But I wonder if it is enough ...

Do you know if I ca be 100% sure that nobody could find a way to submit the form ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set #executes_submit_callback as FALSE

eg : $form['submit']['#executes_submit_callback'] = FALSE;

Drupal Document is  [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#executes_submit_callback)

Answer (score 1):

To make sure nobody submit the form create a custom validate function that always set error on form ,(using [form_set_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7)).

In that validate function you have to check for the circunstnaces that makes the form available to submission or not.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the simple tip ... Ill mix both : not having a submit button and adding a global validation function